# Wildcard in Firebase database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Can we use wildcards in Firebase database rules? From my experiments, it doesn't seem like that's the case. Am I missing something or is that what's supposed to happen?

So, for example, I might have the same rules for all `products_*` entries and it would be easier to group them together using a wildcard.

To clarify, it's an web app and I am concerned with the database permissions that we set in the console. Can we use wildcard there ?

For example,

```
{
"rules": {
    "products_A": {
        <rules>
    },
    "products_B": {
        <rules>
    }
}
```

I would like to have only 1 set of rules like:

```
{
"rules": {
    "products_*": {
        <rules>
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Post your rules as text please, no images and what you are trying to accomplish through wildcards as there may be a solution.

Comment: @Jay, updated with clarification!

Comment: I posted a marvelous answer but because I have suddenly forgotten how to read it was the totally wrong one for the question. On that note... It's still unclear what the question is asking - most firebase rules use a  placeholder to refer to an enclosing parent node. Maybe you can post your current rules and describe what you are after.

Comment: Appreciate your time and help. Clarified my question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firebase offers a wildcard path used to represent ids and dynamic child keys. For example, $uid in the below rules is a 'wildcard' that allows the parameters within that node to refer to the parent node.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in the above example, the $uid is the wildcard path for every user node within the /users node. Here is how the above rules expands per node

```
users
  uid_0 <--------|
                 V
    ".write": "uid_0 === auth.uid" //only user with uid = uid_0 can write
  uid_1
    ".write": "uid_1 === auth.uid" //only user with uid = uid_1 can write
  uid_2
    ".write": "uid_2 === auth.uid" //only user with uid = uid_1 can write
```

You can expand on this to provide a great level of flexibility. Say you want a certain set of users to be able to access a groups node. The group rules could be

```
  "rules": {
    "Groups": {
       "$group_id" : {
         ".read": "root.child('Allowed_Users/' + auth.uid).val() === $group_id",
         ".write": "root.child('Allowed_Users/' + auth.uid).val() === $group_id"
       }
    }
```

This limits access to each group node to a certain set of users, specified in the Allowed_Users node. The data in the Firebase database could look like:

```
Groups
   group_0
     //data
   group_1
     //data


Allowed_Users
   uid_0: group_0
   uid_1: group_0
```

Is this example, users uid_0 and uid_1 could read/write to group_0 but not read/write to group_1